# Deserializing POCO types with same properties in Queue with QueueTriggerAttribute?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

How to make it deserialize to original type? WebJobs SDK allows to specify the type of a POCO object and add `QueueTriggerAttribute` near it to make it function ([the doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues#poco-plain-old-clr-object-queue-messages)). Now it deserializes not to an original type but some other (from run to run it varies). Here is the code:

```cs
public class PocoCommandA { public string Prop { get; set; } }

public class PocoCommandB { public string Prop { get; set; } }

public static void Func1([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] PocoCommandA aCommand)
{... }

public static void Func2([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] PocoCommandB bCommand)
{ ... }
```

And it calls `Fun2` (or some other) when

```cs
var a = new PocoCommandA();
var cloudQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a));

await queue.AddMessageAsync(cloudQueueMessage);
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to deserialize messages in queue to PocoCommandA and PocoCommandB type? If so, it seems that there are many messages in queue. And their  field name are the same. Only the class name are different. So we can not determine which message belongs to which class.

Answer (score 1):

If PocoCommandA and PocoCommandB 2 classes has the same properties that it can't 
know which message belong to specific object. As it could be any of the 2 Objects. Generally, we don't recommond that 2 classes have the same properties.

If PocoCommandA and PocoCommandB 2 classes have the different properties, then if we send the Poco message to queue, then corresponding function will be triggered. And we no need to deserialize it. We could use the aCommand or bCommand directly.

Comment: Really frustrating. How to workaround this? Adding a unique property should work, right? But that doesn't look clean.

Comment: How does having two classes with same props look clean? Why can't you have a single one?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by manually handling serialization / deserialization.  This entails that handling of the messages are done using `switch` (could be Reflection of course).

Deserialize:

```cs
var message = (IMessage) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(msg, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
} );
```

Serialize:

```cs
new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg, /* the same */));
```

WebJobs SDK place where it is handled is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/663a508e8a851629c26a51e7de3af36629dfd120/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Protocols/JsonSerialization.cs). But it is not configurable. [Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1639) created there.